# Expression of the exponential integral $E_1$ using standard functions with real arguments

Tags: complex-analysis, numerical-methods

In standard numeric packages (for C++) the function $$E_1(z)=\int_1^\infty \frac{e^{-zt}}{t}dt$$
is only implemented for real arguments. For a specific calculation I need to be able to evaluate this function for all complex $z$. My hope is, that this can be acomplished using "standard" special function with real argument only (where with standard I mean accessible to numerics using e.g. the GSL).

Can this be achieved, and if so, how?

Comment: Are you sure, there isn't a minus sign missing, i.e. $\exp(-zt)$ instead of $\exp(zt)$?

Comment: Thanks, you are right (just changed it) but it does not really affect the problem...

Comment: Could you use the pseudo code presented in Figure 2 of [this paper](http://www.cs.utah.edu/~vpegorar/research/2011_JGT/paper.pdf) to simply write your own function for complex arguments?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [DLMF](http://dlmf.nist.gov/6.2), sections 6.2-6.5. It appears the answer is no. It provides a Methods of Computation section with references to papers and sometimes code. Also, specfun.f, which you can find scattered online, provides a simple implementation in Fortran (see e.g. [here](http://jean-pierre.moreau.pagesperso-orange.fr/Fortran/me1z_f90.txt)) that can be easily translated into C/C++.

Answer (score 0):

[Julia's](https://julialang.org/) [SpecialFunctions package](https://github.com/JuliaMath/SpecialFunctions.jl) includes exponential integrals of arbitrary complex arguments (and arbitrary orders, even complex orders).  It is callable from C/C++ by linking to `libjulia` and writing a few lines of C/C++ code to get a compiled function pointer, as explained in [this thread on stackexchange](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/23194/i-am-searching-for-a-c-code-implementing-the-complex-polygamma-function/23733#23733)